# Getting overflow auto to work on a list of buttons

Tags: css, overflow

I've been trying to get this list of buttons to have a scroll bar and scroll on table and smaller screens. I've add two divs for inner and outter to add overflow: hidden on outter and overflow: auto on inner. I can't seem to get this to work. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Created a JSFiddle as asked and it works here. Maybe it is an issue with my SASS

http://jsfiddle.net/tuckerjoenz/p9afq4y9/

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle-outer">
  <div class="circle-button-menu-container">
    <ul class="field field-name-field-link-button field-type-entityreference field-label-hidden">
      <li class="link-button">
        <span property="dc:title" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span>
        <a class="circle-button" href="#parents">
          <div class="circle-image">
            <img class="active" src="../images/Parent_2_0.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="button-title">Parents</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="link-button">
        <span property="dc:title" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span>
        <a class="circle-button" href="#kids">
          <div class="circle-image">
            <img class="active" src="../images/kids_JPEG_0.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="button-title">Kids</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="link-button">
        <span property="dc:title" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span>
        <a class="circle-button" href="#educators">
          <div class="circle-image">
            <img class="active" src="../images/Educator_JPEG_0.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="button-title">Educators</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="link-button">
        <span property="dc:title" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span>
        <a class="circle-button" href="#volunteer">
          <div class="circle-image">
            <img class="active" src="../images/volunteer_JPEG_0.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="button-title">Volunteer</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SASS**

```
.circle-outer {
  height: 350px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -200px;
  padding: 100px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;

  .circle-button-menu-container {
    overflow: auto;
    .field-name-field-link-button {
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      width: 1000%;
      z-index: 100;
      list-style-type: none;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      .link-button {
        margin: 0px 46px 10px;
        float: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 170px;
        a.circle-button {
          display: block;
          text-decoration: none;
          .circle-image {
            border: 10px solid white;
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px gray;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 170px;
            height: 170px;
            img {
              display: block;
              min-width: 100%;
              min-height: 100%;
              width: 100%;
            }
            &:hover, &:active {
              border: 10px solid #b6b6b6;
              box-shadow: none;
            }
          }
          .button-title {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #40749e;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            margin-top: 10px;
          }
          &:before, &:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: transparent;
            border-bottom: 0;
          }
          &:before {
            bottom: -33px;
            left: 39%;
            border-top-color: #b6b6b6;
            border-width: 17px;
          }
          &:after {
            bottom: -28px;
            left: 40%;
            border-top-color: #fff;
            border-width: 15px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured this out. I had to remove the `position: absolue` on the `.circle-button-menu-container` class and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You  could try overflow:scroll

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? I'll check it out